# Plotting and saving a list of time series in R

Tags: r, list, plot, time-series, lapply

Hi I have a list of 67 time series objects which I would like to plot and then save these plots as jpeg files under different names. Here is a preview of this list:

```
$ SE_VALUES_IMV_IN          :List of 3
  ..$ 220830  : num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083030: num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083082: num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 2010 2010 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "ts"
 $ SI_VALUES_IMV_EU28_EXTRA  :List of 8
  ..$ 220830  : num [1:84] 235549 117953 163342 214415 248162 ...
  ..$ 22083011: num [1:84] 8026 0 0 6166 0 ...
  ..$ 22083030: num [1:84] 0 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083041: num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083071: num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 55910 ...
  ..$ 22083079: num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083082: num [1:84] 227523 117913 163342 207068 192252 ...
  ..$ 22083088: num [1:84] 0 0 0 1181 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 2010 2011 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "ts"
 $ SI_VALUES_IMV_EU28_INTRA  :List of 12
  ..$ 220830  : num [1:84] 218674 255317 327377 363219 335267 ...
  ..$ 22083011: num [1:84] 9363 10129 19672 20631 10403 ...
  ..$ 22083019: num [1:84] 0 1978 0 0 7116 ...
  ..$ 22083030: num [1:84] 3837 15684 14588 20487 30870 ...
  ..$ 22083041: num [1:84] 18979 5123 7176 36842 9390 ...
  ..$ 22083049: num [1:84] 688 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083061: num [1:84] 0 0 3452 4225 96 ...
  ..$ 22083069: num [1:84] 0 0 0 40 0 0 7520 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083071: num [1:84] 139915 204803 256095 218105 185088 ...
  ..$ 22083079: num [1:84] 0 3219 0 0 3381 ...
  ..$ 22083082: num [1:84] 45892 14381 26394 62889 88527 ...
  ..$ 22083088: num [1:84] 0 0 0 0 396 0 0 0 642 105 ...
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 2010 2011 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "ts"
```

So I have written a function to plot (using `ts.plot()`) these elements by applying `lapply()` to my list:

```
fun2 <- function(x){
  mypath <- file.path("C:","Users","Documents", "FI-R", "graphs", paste("multiplot-", x ,".jpeg", sep = ""))
  jpeg(file=mypath, width = 10, height = 10, units = 'in', res = 400)
  ts.plot(x, col = 1:ncol(x), ylab="Import Value", main=deparse(substitute(x))) 
  legend("topleft", colnames(x), col = 1:ncol(x), lty = 1)
  dev.off()}


Plot.Ts.whisk.lst <- lapply(Ts.whisk.lst.2, fun2)
```

This is of course not working, but it shows my ambition. I have tried to simplify the problem to just running the code below:

```
Plot.Ts.whisk.lst <- lapply(Ts.whisk.lst.2, function(x) ts.plot(x) )
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, NULL, log = log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I know there is a problem with my list of time series but can't understand what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a single ts (coerce by double), which was solved with using. Not sure if it will work with yours.

Try it with 2 ts and run your code only with those.

```
ts$Value <- as.numeric(as.character(ts$Value))
```

Did you try plotting a single ts?